# Fail to load library in r script on sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, r, package

I am having big trouble using the ncdf4-package in an R-script on SQL server 2016. I have a long script, but everything boils down to these lines:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script  @language =N'R',
@script=N'library(ncdf4)'
GO
```

Which give me the error:

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 10
>   A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
>   Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   An external script error occurred:
>
> Invalid BXL stream"

The package is installed in the right place. Ran this script to verify:

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language=N'R'  
,@script = N'str(OutputDataSet);  
packagematrix <- installed.packages();  
NameOnly <- packagematrix[,1];  
OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(NameOnly);'  
,@input_data_1 = N'SELECT 1 as col'  
WITH RESULT SETS ((PackageName nvarchar(250) ))
```

The package name shows on the list. It is totally impossible to load the package. I have ran several other packages with no problems, so i think the permissions are ok. SQL Server 2016 runs on a virtual machine with 14 Gb ram and I have allocated up to 75% of the memory to the program with this line of code:

```
ALTER RESOURCE POOL "default" WITH (max_memory_percent = 75);
```

So I cannot imagine that this is due to memory limits. 84% of the ram is free. It works on RStudio. Plees help

Comment: possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655141/sql-2016-with-r-error-hresult-0x80004004

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Stevieb143's problem is that the package isn't found. If I add 
    print(.libPaths())
to the script, it points to the correct library which contains the package files.